# Spherical aberration in a virtual 3D perspective camera

Tags: opengl, 3d, webgl, projection

A virtual 3D world maps points in space to a 3-dimensional grid along x-, y- and z-axes. Suppose a perspective camera looks into a virtual world from the point (0, 0, 0), looking down the positive z-axis in a left-handed system. Imagine that the far plane is 2 units wide and 2 units high, and that its z coordinate is 1. This means that the point in top left of the scene is at the position (1, 1, 1).

The horizontal distance to the point directly in front of the camera, at (0, 0, 1) is 1 unit, but the horizontal distance to the far right corner, at (1, 0, 1) is a little over 1.414 units. To maintain the same sense of perspective as when viewing directly ahead, a point at this distance at a height of 1 units should appear to be 0.707 units above the horizon. Instead, it appears exactly 1 unit above the horizon.

If you turn the camera to point directly at the point at (1, 0, 1), the vertical dimensions of objects in that direction are reduced: the scene appears to distort. When the field of view is fairly wide, this can lead to a feeling of nausea when the camera needs to turn a lot.

Is my understanding correct? If so, is there a way to correct this aberration at the corners of an OpenGL/WebGL scene? Or is it something that users have learned to live with?

Comment: Don't forget that you are projecting/viewing this on a flat screen, but "seeing" it as though it was a sphere. It's been a while since I did this, but I think it means that the distortions are cancelled out by the brain. (It's very easy to fool the human visual system)